# Why git branch command does not work to create a new branch?

Tags: git, github

Trying my hands on Git und GitHub. I have three workstations at different locations and want to use it as per my time and location. At the this moment, I am at home and want to create work on the code which I already created in at school's PC.

The following command gives me `fatal error`:

```
python@DESKTOP-6RBC9EL MINGW64 ~/Desktop/project/react-complete-guide (master)

$ git branch home_pc

fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'
```

How many git versions are available to create, delete and modify branch names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new branch, use:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

And to change to a different branch, use:

```
git checkout branch_name
```

Comment: thank you for your help. May I ask please how to delete the branch?

Comment: Yes, use: git branch -d branch_name, and git branch -D branch_name to force (be careful if you have uncommited changes) Please press the arrow facing up to vote it was a useful answer and other people can see it!.